Manhwa - two people transmigrate, one into a sickly prince. The other person had read the book
It is an isekai with two people who transmigrated. The ML transmigrated randomly into a sickly prince, and the FL is the one who read the book and transmigrated. They first encounter each other when the FL is at the castle (either to break up with one of the princes or tell him she’s no longer interested in him) and she walks past the ML's garden and sees him. They decide to meet up afterwards, where they scope each other out for being suspicious. They eventually have another meeting to discuss about how they’re both Korean, their names, etc. I believe they both live in different universes? because when they talk about politicians and etc they recall different people.

That's a lot of nice details. Did you read this on a particular website, do you remember? Was it all in color? Just covers? Do you remember anyone's hair color (it can be an easy way to check if it's the right work at a glance)? You can [edit] any details into your question.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

I recall a manhua, a man transmigrated to a world where he's Not the MC of the "Story" the world's based on, but only a minor character (I think he had played the computer games the book was based on, and was trying to influence the events to change the story. (not to improve his position, but to change most people's path in the story to be better.)  The person who had read the book and practically knew it by heart, had also transmigrated into the world. But quickly realizes something is changing the story, and it must be a reborn person or a transmigrated person but does not know who.

Essentially, the first transmigrator is such a minor character, he is hardly mentioned in the book, So the second transmigrator does not notice if something about the first has changed, cause he has so little info on that character.  At the point I had stopped, if I remember right, they were not really aware of the other, but maybe meet later in the manhua and have the event the OP described.
